# Get values from pipe delimited file to the normal text file in Linux

Tags: text-processing

I have a pipe delimited file

Lookup.txt:

```
Column1|yellow|value|628291
Column9|red|value|346801
```

File.txt:

```
Yellow
YellowDiamond
Redgold
```

I am trying to get the value of **Yellow** present In File.txt to the exact match from pipe delimited file I.e Lookup.txt. The output should be the entire line as shown below.
File.txt file are having the values to search in the file Lookup.txt

I tried `awk`, `fgrep` commands but they are giving me different values; The expected output is:

```
Column1|yellow|value|628291
```

Comment: Show us what you try.

Comment: Should the match be limited to a specific *field* of the pipe-delimited file? Should it be case-insensitive, as implied by your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason why your `grep` approach didn't work?

```
grep -Fwif File.txt Lookup.txt
```

looks promising...?

Comment: It IS working with the sample data you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Store the strings from `File.txt` as keys in an associative array in `awk`. For case-insensitive comparison, fold the keys to, e.g., lower-case.

When the second file, `Lookup.txt`, is being read, test whether the second field's lower-cased value is a key in the associative array.  If it is, print the whole line.

```bsh
awk -F '|' 'NR == FNR { key[tolower($0)]; next } (tolower($2) in key)' File.txt Lookup.txt
```

The variables `NR` and `FNR` hold the number of lines read overall and the number of lines read from the current file, respectively.  If the values of these variables are the same, we're reading from the first file.